# How to generate [InlineData] dynamically on runtime in xunit [Theory]?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xunit

The task is to generate `InlineData` during runtime. I've tried inherited `DataAttribute` with my `GetData()` method, `MemberData`, `ClassData` generators. But after I build the test project, tests are already generated.

```
public class MyCustomDataAttribute: DataAttribute
{
  public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
  {
    yield return new object[] { false; }
    if (myRuntimeCondition) 
    {
      yield return new object[] { true; }      
    }
  }
}
```

Kind of that.

Comment: What is your problem with the tests being already generated after build? Your method will provide all the input data you need.

Comment: The problem is the data I need will be read from the database. And each environment (dev/stg/prod) has it's own set of data

Comment: I had heard comments that MemberData didn't generate the tests in advance but only at runtime, in contrast to ClassData; if you're having problems I suppose this has been changed.